# Looking for command line (debian if possible) tool doing screenshot of webpage

Tags: linux, command-line, screenshot, scripting

The topic is less easy than it looks.

I need to be able to get `png` or `jpg` screenshot from some website on specific interval.

So a simple `cron` job is OK, but I can't find a tool that really works.
I tried more than 10 that I found on google, but most of them are out of date or buggy, complaining that there is no more compatibility with current packages, etc.

For the ones which did work, the rendering is poor and do not consider Javascript or allow for certain JS events to trigger the screenshot.
For instance, let's say I would like to capture the following a Google Maps page: https://www.google.com/maps/@46.9420866,8.5839928,14z.

I would like this page to be screenshotted repeatedly.

As mentioned in the title, I need a script or application: I can't use an "end-user" software that will need interaction (such as classic screenshot tools).

If you know any tool that works with a current Debian (or any other Linux distro, for that matter) version, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try headless Chrome.

The command is

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.example.com/
```

(the --disable-gpu flag is rarely needed, on on some Windows machines, I think)

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome):

> Running with `--screenshot` will produce a file named `screenshot.png` in the current working directory. If you're looking for full page screenshots, things are a tad more involved. There's a great blog post from David Schnurr that has you covered. Check out [Using headless Chrome as an automated screenshot tool](https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you've tried and rejected, but if `scrot` isn't among those, it would  seem to fulfill your needs.  It can take a screenshot of a specific window, it has a configurable image quality level, and a cron job can be set up to take screenshots at a specific interval.

Comment: scrot is a real screenshot feature, but it requires GUI. Anyway thanks for the idea, i'll dig it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the site was built (ie, one of the javascript messes with angular,etc or just HTML) you could ...

use `wget` to mirror the page to a local file, along with all requisites (images, etc).

use one of the HTML -> PDF converters to create a PDF of the page.

use `pdf2tiff` to convert it to a TIFF image.

use whatever image utility (`imagemagick`/`convert`) to turn the TIFF into a PNG, JPG, etc.

Glue all of that together wiht some `bash` shell scripting or `python` or even `php` or whatever other reasonable programming language you are comfortable with.